# Flutter sliver title from center to left when collapsing

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

My goal is to follow what I designed (inspired by Samsung weather) but implementing the code is difficult when you're just starting to learn. When expanded the title should be centered and when collapsed will stay in the upper left.

[image]

So far this is my code and my current progress. The tricky part is to move the title to the center.

```
      Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        body: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
            SliverAppBar(
              actions: <Widget>[
                IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.search),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              ],
              pinned: _pinned,
              snap: _snap,
              floating: _floating,
              expandedHeight: 160,
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              elevation: 0.0,
              flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                titlePadding: EdgeInsets.all(18),
                // centerTitle: true,
                title: Text('Panahon'),
              ),
            ),
            SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child: SizedBox(
              height: 800,
              child: Card(),
            ))
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

[image]

[image]

edit: The app dynamically changes themes dependent on the time.

Comment: try the Align widget and alignment.center on the title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create custom sliver app bar by using `SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate`, you will get `shrinkOffset` that can be used to animate app bar elements.

Run on [dartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=b7861e5ef83db7a3ad0f04e3a0cdb81d)

Replace your `SliverAppBar` with this

```dart
SliverPersistentHeader(
  pinned: true,
  delegate: MySliverHeaderDelegate(onActionTap: () {
    debugPrint("on Tap");
  }),
),
```

And custom `SliverHeaderDelegate`

```dart
class MySliverHeaderDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  final double _maxExtent = 160;
  final VoidCallback onActionTap;

  MySliverHeaderDelegate({
    required this.onActionTap,
  });
  @override
  Widget build(
      BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    debugPrint(shrinkOffset.toString());
    return Container(
      color: Colors.cyanAccent,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment(
                //little padding
                -(shrinkOffset > _maxExtent - 20
                        ? _maxExtent - 20
                        : shrinkOffset) /
                    _maxExtent,
                0),
            child: const Text('Panahon'),
          ),

          // here provide actions
          Positioned(
            top: 0,
            right: 0,
            child: IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.search),
              onPressed: onActionTap,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  double get maxExtent => _maxExtent;

  @override
  double get minExtent => kToolbarHeight;

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(covariant MySliverHeaderDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return oldDelegate != this;
  }
}
```